# One NxM array or N arrays of size M?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array, scientific-computing

I'm running a scientific computation and need to store velocities of particles. To store the 3 components, should I use 3 different arrays or single 1x3 array? Will it affect my computation in any way?

My number of particles will be large, may even go up to 1e10 or more. I will be using C++.

Comment: That highly depends on the way in which you will be accessing the data. There are different algorithms that will benefit either way, due to caching among other factors.

Comment: Your title says NxM, but your body says 1x3. Why would you use a 1x3 array? Did you mean Nx3 in the body?

Comment: This is a particular case of the age-old Array-Of-Structures vs Structure-Of-Arrays question. As @twalberg says, it just depends on your array access.  If you'll be operating along one dimension more than the others - all of (say) the x-components of velocities together, as vs all the components of velocity of each particle - it makes sense to keep that data close together.  But note that here you'd get that benefit by having your array be ordered as (e.g.) `double vel[NPTS][NDIMS]` vs `double vel[NDIMS][NPTS]` - having actually separate arrays `vx[NPTS], vy[NPTS], vz[NPTS]` would be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to **firstly** write readable and maintainable code and only then optimize.

In C++, as in in the good old C, memory is allocated in one big chunk (min. is 10240 bytes) internally by `brk` or `sbrk`. So imagine that you have previously allocated and freed some memory.

Case 1: You create 3 arrays. Most probably, there would be some free chunks among the used ones. So it would basically iterate over the list of free chunks and place them according to the algorithm, probably best-fit (**but not only**). Either way, it would (or could, since it's runtime there is no distinct answer) scatter them over the already allocated memory. Say 1 is in the middle, then the other two are in the end.

Case 2: You create 1 array. Then it would be allocated at one place. Either newly acquired storage or available one.

So I would go with the 1x3 2-dimensional array. That way you would benefit from the locality of reference principle, specifically *memory locality*.

However,as I said, you should be sure that using the 2-dimensional array won't hurt readability in terms of connectivity of the data.

I hope this sheds some light!

Comment: I believe modern allocators tend to use `mmap` rather than `sbrk`. Overall, your advice seems reasonable. On a CPU one 3-component array should be only slightly faster than 3 1-component ones. However on a GPU (think OpenCL or Cuda) it would be significantly faster, due to mostly non-existing caching of global memory.

Comment: Yes, agree. I just tried to be as basic as possible.

Comment: `[1][3]`? What? Are you assuming N=1? Or are you thinking that each particle gets its own array/set of arrays? The options here are one Nx3 array for all particle velocity data or 3 arrays of length N representing x, y, and z components of all particle velocities.

Comment: wait... the question body says 1x3. Weird. There must be a typo in either the title or body. I'm guessing the 1x3 is a typo.

Comment: Edited it to remove any unclarity.